# Get information from a HTML page

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm novice and I'm trying to understand how to get information from a webpage, I've already read about HtmlAgilityPack and I'm using it, but after 2 days trying to understand how I can do this, here am I asking for help.

Ok, the thing is:  I want to read some informations from a page and write it in a label text.

The page I'll use as example is: http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Huur
I want to show in different labels the level, the vocation and the guild informations...
But, all I got is this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myWeb As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
    Dim myDoc = myWeb.Load("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=" & TextBox1.Text.Trim())
    Dim myRoot As HtmlNode = myDoc.DocumentNode
    Dim myElements As List(Of HtmlElement) = New List(Of HtmlElement)
    Dim MainContentArea As HtmlNode

    myWeb.Load("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=" & TextBox1.Text.Trim())
    MainContentArea = myDoc.GetElementbyId("characters")

    TextBox2.Text = MainContentArea.InnerHtml
End Sub
```

As you guys can see, I found a way to read all the character informations, but I don't know how to find the thing that I want that is: level, vocation and guild informations and show it in differents labels text.

Can you guys help me please? :}

(In the code I'm using Textbox2.Text to show the page content cause it shows alot of things and I've got errors when trying to show the content in a label text.)

Sorry for the bad english guys.

Comment: Your English isn't bad at all.  I've seen far worse from native English speakers and writers.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest looking at [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) if you aren't familiar with it.  Secondly, you will need to figure out your `html` structure.  You can use Firefox and go to what you are looking for and right-click on inspect element.  It will lay out the structure of the document and give you information you can use for the `xpath`.

For instance if you want to get the level you can use "/html/body//div[@class='BoxContent'/table/body/tr[td='Level:']/td" to get the  element that contains the level indicator and then move to the `HtmlNode.NextSibling` to get the next  element whose text contains the value of the level you are looking for.

I hope that is enough to get you started.